# Git add to existing remote repo that I pulled from

Tags: git

I decided to cut my losses on a big error and start over.  I pulled in my code from my bitbucket repo:

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init
git pull origin master
```

Then I did some work.  I went did the add, commit,but when I went to "push origin master" I received the error...

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I think I was supposed to "clone" instead of "pull"?  Or I needed to do 'git remote add origin //pathtomyrepo.git'?  I'm confused about that because it's already there on my repo and I'm not clear what the 'git remote add origin' would do.  Either way, now I'm not sure what to do next...  I want to save the new work to the repo and carry forward with development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git clone` is essentially a shortcut for `git init` + `git pull`, so I do not see a reason why you should not have used `git clone` in the first place.

But not everything is lost, don't worry. One thing that `git clone` does and that you did not do is to define a "remote", i.e. store in Git's configuration file the location of the remote repository. As you guessed, you can do that with

```
git remote add origin http://example.com/repo/
```

This will add a few lines in your `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://example.com/repo/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And then you'll be able to say `origin` to talk about the remote repository.

You probably also want to set your remote as default upstream branch for your master branch (which `git clone` does for you) :

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then, a simple argumentless `git push` will do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clear answer and simple to follow.  This makes so much sense and gives me a better idea of what 'git clone' does, too, obviously that would have been a better choice.  Thanks agin!